# awk script in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I want to use a awk-script inside of an bash-script. Somehow it doesn't work right.

This is my bash script:

```
 1 #!/bin/bash
 2
 3
 4 echo "In what file do you want to look?"
 5 read input
 6 input="1D-MA.mcr"
 7
 8 echo "What are you looking for?"
 9 read muster
10
11 echo "What is the new value?"
12 read newVal
13
14 echo "What is the name of the new file?"
15 read output
16 
18 awk -v muster="${muster}" value="${newVal}" replace.awk "$input" > "$output"
```

and this is my awk script

```
 1 #!/usr/bin/awk -f
 2
 3 $1 == "$!VARSET" && $2 ~ muster { split($2, tmp, "=");  $2=tmp[1] "=" value; print }
 4 $1 != "$!VARSET" || $2 !~ muster
```

Right now the bash script just takes the awk-script and writes it in front of the input-file.

Edit: I found an answer.

changed the bash script to:

```
 1 #!/bin/bash
 2
 3
 4 echo "In what file do you want to look?"
 5 read input
 6 input="1D-MA.mcr"
 7
 8 echo "What are you looking for?"
 9 read muster
10
11 echo "What is the new value?"
12 read newVal
13
14 echo "What is the name of the new file?"
15 read output
16 
18 awk -v muster="${muster}" value="${newVal}" -f replace.awk "$input" > "$output"
```

and removed the -f in the awk-script

```
 1 #!/usr/bin/awk 
 2
 3 $1 == "$!VARSET" && $2 ~ muster { split($2, tmp, "=");  $2=tmp[1] "=" value; print }
 4 $1 != "$!VARSET" || $2 !~ muster
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use the option f? E.g.  awk -f replace.awk

Comment: yes that was the problem. Thanks

Comment: This had nothing to do with the `-f` inside the awk script - that whole first line that starts with a `#` is just a comment to awk and as such is completely ignored by the script. awk is not shell and so `#!` inside an awk script is not a shebang, it's just a comment. Also, your script can be simplifed to `$1 == "$!VARSET" && $2 ~ muster { split($2, tmp, "=");  $2=tmp[1] "=" value } {print}` rather than testing the negation of the condition on the second line.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question (how to run an awk script inside a bash script), here is an example how you embed an awk script into your bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "This is bash speaking ..."    

awk -f /dev/stdin << EOF    
   BEGIN { print "... and this is actually awk!"; }    
EOF    

echo " ... and now it's me again, bash :-)"
```

Comment: No, that's not how you do it. You just do `awk 'BEGIN { print "... and this is actually awk!" }'`

Comment: Hey, this i s a nice trick. How is this enchantment called?